# No sound into headphones

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I will make it quick : I have no sound in my headphones when they are plugged in on my Asus F200CA running Ubuntu 14.04, but :

- I have sound in the laptop speakers when the headphones are plugged out.
- If I boot up my laptop on a Live USB running Ubuntu 14.04, I have sound in the speakers and in the headphones.
- If I open `pavucontrol`, I can "see" sound, but I can't hear it.

I already did some of the actions listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, with Unity, and this bug appeared about a week ago.

Comment: For info, [here are the output of the command](http://quack1.me/upload/debug_pulseaudio/result_command.txt) listed [in the step 4](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure#Step_4).

Comment: I can "see" the sound coming out, but I can't hear it. `pavucontrol` seems to see sound coming out : see [screenshot here](http://quack1.me/upload/debug_pulseaudio/screenshot.png)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem for days (on a different laptop). The solution was to do the following two things:

1. Reset user configuration (as described in the Troubleshooting section of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio).
2. Make sure **Independent HP** is **Disabled** in `alsamixer`. To do that, just type `alsamixer` in a terminal, then choose your sound card (by pressing **F6**) and move to the **Independent HP** column.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In my case I uninstalled pavucontrol without intention. I ran `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` and the problem was solved immediately.

Comment: This was also the solution for me, install pavucontrol, run it, and change my default output to the only other device (there were two, and it periodically gets reset back to the wrong one for reasons unknown)

Comment: There is NO "independent HP" column in alsamixer.

Comment: I can't control the Independent HP, whatever key I press it stays enabled. After insisting and poking around it changed!