# Headphones not working in 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have spent some time searching around the various threads relating to headphone issues in Ubuntu and none of the answers seem to resolve my issue, so I will post it here. This problem started a couple of months back when I was running 15.10, and persists now that I am running 16.04 (upgrade, not clean install).

Whenever I plug headphones into my laptop (Asus X202E-DH31T-SL) there is a strange noise (rising then falling static, followed by a loud pop) and then no sound. Sound comes through the built-in speakers fine, and goes out over HDMI fine. The headphones work with other devices. I have tried several pairs of headphones all to the same effect. Upon plugging the headphones in a dialog now appears stating '**unknown audio device**'.

A dump of ALSA info can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b13297f164d7a5f1e14f3190a5c1d0bcd0102e63/%22here%22).

I have tried the following:

1. Checked `alsamixer` sound levels - no issues.
2. Made changes to `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf` as listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working). No success.
3. Made changes to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working), and tried multiple values for `model` as listed under the ALSA model list. No success. Each time I did a `sudo alsa force-reload` and unplugged/reinserted headphones, to absolutely no avail.
4. Removed and re-installed both `alsamixer` and `pulseaudio` but this was not successful.

A dump from dmesg can be found below
:

```
[    8.261817] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VB: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.261825] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.261829] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1a/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.261832] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.261835] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.261839] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
[    8.273953] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[    8.274480] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9485 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90000d00000, irq=17
[    8.290195] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    8.290321] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
```

Any help much appreciated. I'm at the end of my efforts here, with the next stop being a wipe and clean install to see if that resolves the issue. I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: someone with a similar problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/484122/no-sound-into-headphones

Comment: Do you have a combined headphone/microphone jack, or two separate jacks?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. That worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/622531/354942